# Javascript: creating a class equivalent to new Image()

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

How does one create a class like **new Image()**?
example:

I add a prototype to this class like: `Image.prototype.convert = function() {}`

```
const img = new Image();
console.log(img) //will return the <img> element
```

And I can still execute img.convert();

So I created a class like so:

```
class Video {

    constructor() {

        return document.createElement("VIDEO");

    }

    convert() {

        console.log("converted");

    }

}
```

This way I will not be able to access new Video.convert(), because all I will get is the element.
Yet if I don't return an element in the constructor, new Video will just return a class.

So side by side:

```
const img = new Image();
const vid = new Video();
console.log(img) //<img>
console.log(vid) //<<video>
img.convert() // *converted*
vid.convert() //error: vid.convert is not a function
```

Comment: You must not `return` an object from the constructor. Your `vid` is not a `Video` instance.

Comment: "*new Video will just return a class*" - not sure what you mean by that, also, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Why not just create a property on [`HTMLVideoElement.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) if you want to do the same as creating a property on `Image.prototype`? (Notice that [either is a bad idea](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) still)

Comment: https://dev.to/giantmachines/stop-using-javascript-classes-33ij

Comment: Thats interesting @Bergi thanks, the article is more than 12 years old tho and talks about browser versions of back then, is it still as relevant today?

Comment: Interesting @KooiInc, I've always thought using classes made my code look more readable, but I might give this a try.

Comment: @Hash Yes, apart from the Internet Exploder thing, all the points are still valid today.

Answer (score 0):

After the helpfull comments I received, I realised that extending the DOM is not as good of an idea as I first thought. As it could cause collision with potential other libs, decrease performance and more. Even as wrapping could fix the collision issue, writing it would not be as convenient and there is still the performance issue.

I guess some alternatives are just writing Utility functions, Helper objects or even use CustomElementRegistry.